# Get value checkbox from p:selectedCheckbox javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, primefaces

I have a JavaScript function and I want to assign checked value to `fixedLoss()` JavaScript function. I call `fixedLoss()` function but I don't take checked value info with PrimeFaces.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="fixedLossId" value="#{chargebackBean.selectedChargebackCategory.fixedLoss}">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="fixedLossDateTime" oncomplete="fixedLoss()" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<script>
    function fixedLoss() {
        if (fixedLossSelected ??) {
            ...
        }
        else {
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: 1: please correct your title... `p:selectedChekboc`? 2: please post version info, 3: Search.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183078/how-to-get-a-value-of-jsf-selectbooleancheckbox-by-using-javascript 4: please state what you tried to access it.

Comment: `p:selectedCheckbox` ???

Comment: Using prime faces liblary ı will edit this tittle  @Kukeltje

Comment: You can also get it using jQuery like `jQuery("[id$='fixedLossId']").find("input").attr("aria-checked");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a `widgetVar` attribute to your widget:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="fixedLossId"
                      value="#{chargebackBean.selectedChargebackCategory.fixedLoss}"
                      widgetVar="checkBox"
                      >
    <p:ajax event="change" update="fixedLossDateTime" oncomplete="fixedLoss()" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

And then use it to access to the control:

```
 $(PF('checkBox').input).is(':checked');
```

Comment: Thanks @Oscar I will try. this seems to solution

Comment: Like in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506746/how-to-know-that-primefaces-selectbooleancheckbox-is-selected-or-not-using-javas